deploy Tensorflow model on AWS
I have built a tensorflow model to classify images.
I now would like to understand best practices to deploy it.
Currently I have serverless pipeline (sqs, lambdas, dynamo) and the logic block where the model would go is one of the lambdas towards the end of the pipeline, to predict and store output into Dynamo.
so what I have is my model, built locally (a Mac), saved as a Keras file, copied into the image I use in the lambda.
In the lambda I
use
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(model_path)
...
y_pred_probs = model.predict(file)

the code eventually works.
Is just i get several logs messages like
 15:29:27.953734: I external/local_xla/xla/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
 15:29:28.064697: I external/local_xla/xla/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
 15:29:28.135335: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:477] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1733239768.219460      14 cuda_dnn.cc:8310] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
E0000 00:00:1733239768.242564      14 cuda_blas.cc:1418] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
 15:29:28.398451: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
 15:29:29,567 - tensorflow - DEBUG - Falling back to TensorFlow client; we recommended you install the Cloud TPU client directly with pip install cloud-tpu-client.
 15:29:29,987 - h5py._conv - DEBUG - Creating converter from 7 to 5
 15:29:29,987 - h5py._conv - DEBUG - Creating converter from 5 to 7
 15:29:29,987 - h5py._conv - DEBUG - Creating converter from 7 to 5
 15:29:29,987 - h5py._conv - DEBUG - Creating converter from 5 to 7
 15:29:30,677 - helper.logger - DEBUG - poppler path is /bin/
 15:29:30,677 - helper.logger - INFO - /var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin
 15:29:30,677 - helper.logger - INFO - DEBUG
 15:29:30.685429: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:152] failed call to cuInit: INTERNAL: CUDA error: Failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)

which seems syntomatic of something not right..
the requirements in the lambda have the tensorflow package.
the lambda takes ages to start
Duration: 1573.59 ms    Billed Duration: 8741 ms    Memory Size: 4000 MB    Max Memory Used: 1815 MB    Init Duration: 7167.20 ms

so wondering, maybe it has something to do with how this image is built?
I am using as base image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
RUN yum -y install poppler-utils && \
yum -y install tar gzip zlib freetype-devel \
        gcc \
        ghostscript \
        lcms2-devel \
        libffi-devel \
        libimagequant-devel \
        libjpeg-devel \
        libraqm-devel \
        libtiff-devel \
        libwebp-devel \
        make \
        openjpeg2-devel \
        sudo \
        tcl-devel \
        tk-devel \
        tkinter \
        which \
        xorg-x11-server-Xvfb \
        zlib-devel; \

following
aws docs

is there a way to improve ?
what is the best way to deploy this?

